# Why do I get an #n/a error when shrinking range of an otherwise working Average function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I had an average function in my spreadsheet that was working well:     `=AVERAGE(
    IF('Sheet2'!$2:$2="Tuesday", IF('Sheet2'!7:7<>"",
       'Sheet2'!7:7)))`

Instead of using all of row 7 in the average calculation, I wanted to only work within a small range, so I changed the formula to this:    `=AVERAGE(
    IF('Sheet2'!$2:$2="Tuesday", IF('Sheet2'!B7:Y7<>"",
       'Sheet2'!B7:Y7)))`

When I make this change, my formula returns a #n/a error. There are no #n/a's in the range `'Sheet2'!B7:Y7`.

What would be causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Excel 2007` or later versions then there is an inbuilt single function `AVERAGEIF`. That might be easier for you, it doesn't required `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` and there's no need to check the range for blanks (`AVERAGEIF` ignores those anyway) so you could use this formula

`=AVERAGEIF(Sheet2!$B2:$Y2,"Tuesday",Sheet2!$B7:$Y7)`

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `=AVERAGE( IF('Sheet2'!$B2:$Y2="Tuesday", IF('Sheet2'!$B$7:$Y$7<>"", 'Sheet2'!$B$7:$Y$7)))`

Since this is an array formula, be sure you push Ctrl+Shift+Enter after typing it.

Excel works with array formulas best when the size of the arrays correspond.
Your original formula was working with the entire row at each section, so if you want to only work with a certain section, edit the entire formula so that it's working with the same number  of cells at each stage of the array formula.

Think of it like this, what it's doing is running an IF test across row 2. 
For argument we'll assume that there are 30 columns, so it runs 30 tests.
For each of those tests it's going and running the sub-if test and finally returning 30 values, which are sent to the average function.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you break out the components of that IF statement into separate cells, and see how they evaluate to True or False.

I think you're problem's in the statement `IF('Sheet2'!$2:$2="Tuesday",  ...)` - as far as I can see, 'Sheet2'!$2:$2 defines a row of cells, rather thn a single value that might be equal to "Tuesday".

Try `='Sheet2'!$A$2="Tuesday"` as your first test, in a single cell on its own. If cell Sheet2!A2 is indeed 'Tuesday', then this formula will evaluate to True.

Comment: This is an array formula, so `IF('Sheet2'!$2:$2="Tuesday", ...)` is accurate.